# Select date in range for each row which is different

Tags: mysql, sql-server, date, select

I want to select 90 days after the date in each row (which are different).

For example:

```
customer A visit a company on 12/3/15: I want to select all 90 dates after 12/3/15 
customer B visit a company on 7/4/11: I want to select all 90 dates after 7/4/11
customer C visit a company on 3/8/13: I want to select all 90 dates after 3/8/13
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you need to add 90 days to date specified in date column as per your screenshot?

Comment: To get 90 dates after `12/3/15` use `DATE_ADD('12/3/15',INTERVAL 90 DAY)`

Comment: Do you have a `calendar` table ?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: To get all different visit dates for customers, 90 days after the specified date you may do : select customerid, visitDate from tlbVisits where VisitDate between @StartDate and DATE_ADD(@StartDate,INTERVAL 90 DAY) group by customerid,VisitDate

Comment: Which RDBMS? And are you storing dates under a DATE data type?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need,

```
Update table set column2 = column1+90
```